# HttpClient does not send cookie when connecting via hostname

Tags: java, cookies, httpclient, apache-httpcomponents

I'm using Apache HttpComponents HttpClient 4.4.1 to communicate with an ASP.Net SOAP service running on IIS (client and server are on the same host as it happens). The SOAP service returns a Set-Cookie header with a session token in response to its AuthenticateUser service. Example:

```
02 22:16:32.994 DEBUG <localhost-startStop-1> [org.apache.http.headers       ]  http-outgoing-1 << Set-Cookie: NTSSOCookie=50d2300d-31cf-4187-820f-83b29949f38b; expires=Sat, 02-Jul-2016 21:16:32 GMT; path=/
...
02 22:16:33.002 DEBUG <localhost-startStop-1> [rotocol.ResponseProcessCookies]  Cookie accepted [NTSSOCookie="50d2300d-31cf-4187-820f-83b29949f38b", version:0, domain:palab46, path:/, expiry:Sat Jul 02 22:16:32 BST 2016]
```

Something peculiar I have observed is that if I connect to the server using just the hostname, the HttpClient library indicates that it has accepted the cookie returned from the server, but never attaches it to outgoing requests for the same connection. If however, I switch to using either the IP address or the FQDN of the server, the cookie is returned just fine.

I've verified the address, port and protocol are consistent across the authentication request and subsequent requests, and also that the cookie path and expiry date values are valid and consistent in all cases.

For kicks, I also checked the hostname and FQDN both resolve to the correct IP address.

What could be causing this odd behaviour?

Comment: what if you use `localhost`?

Comment: Haha, that's a different story altogether! There's a bug in the server application that is preventing localhost or 127.0.0.1 from working correctly at present, which is part of the reason I'm trying to use the hostname instead.

Comment: what if you use another pseudo host name that resolves to the server, as long as the name contains no dot. I'm trying to see whether this is related to TLD.

Comment: Same result - cookie is not sent back to the server. FWIW, I also tried adding a '.hi' to the end of that new hostname and the problem went away again.

Comment: It seems to have a bug with TLDs. The [code](https://github.com/apache/httpclient/blob/trunk/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/cookie/PublicSuffixDomainFilter.java#L74) suggests that it does not honor cookies of TLDs, except "localhost".

Comment: The more serious bug is probably that it confuses cookie origin and cookie domain attribute. In any event, since the `Set-Cookie` header contains no `Domain` attribute, the cookie must be applicable to the origin domain. I wrote an [article](http://bayou.io/draft/cookie.domain.html) about cookie domain issues.